Calling custom api in powerapp with client certificate and secrets to get bearer token
Is there a way to use client certificate, secret, issuer and audience to call api in PowerApps to create a jwt bearer token without writing any custom code, what are the steps?
I do not see a straighforward approach to this as I also need to use sha256  to hash as well.
